# 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, fpm

I'm having the problem that more often than not, if I go to a page on my server that uses php, I get the "502 Bad Gateway" error.

**Error logs:**

`/var/log/nginx/error.log` shows about 3 copies of this error per minute:

```
2016/08/27 15:07:22 [error] 17309#0: *53554 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock 
failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 
[dedicated server], server: localhost, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", 
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: [my IP address]
```

The CPU load from `nginx` or `php5-fpm` processes is sometimes huge (in excess of 100%), but sometimes just noticeable (2%), rarely insignificant.

Here's something I see a lot of in `syslog` (!):

```
Aug 27 15:17:21 [site] avahi-daemon[871]: Invalid response packet from host 
[some IP address that isn't mine and nslookup never heard of].
```

**Things I've tried so far:**

- `apt-get update`
- removed and reinstalled `php5`, `php5-cgi`, and `php5-fpm`
- made sure `apache2` is not running on my system
- [added](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/502-bad-gateway-error-using-nginx/)
  this to `nginx.conf`, inside a `http {` ... `}`:

  `fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
  fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300;`
- ensured that the same user that runs `nginx`, owns `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`.  This is the same owner referenced as `listen.owner` and `listen.group` in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`.
- tried changing the references to that socket to a TCP/IP socket:

  `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` containing the line `fastcgi_pass unix:127.0.0.1:9000;`
  `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` containing the line `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000;`

  Since this made none of the php pages ever work, I reverted that change.
- ensured I'm not disabling PHP files in my `nginx.conf` setup.  I'm not, and sometimes it works, so that can't be it.

**php5-fpm setup:**

I suspect it's a problem with php5 eating up memory or CPU time since (a) it often does and (b) if I don't get that 504 error, I get a very slow load time on any page using php.  Here's what I think is the relevant part of the `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` file:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

So:  what else should I try?  TIA.

Comment: check 1- sudo service php5-fpm status, 2- while changing socket to tcp/ip remove unix, ie, default-> fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000, www.conf-> listen 127.0.0.1:9000; 3- try to increase the process managers for php, i.e., pm.max_children=40, pm.start_servers = 10, pm.min_spare_servers = 5, pm.max_spare_servers = 10 4- switch off keepalive connections from nginx.conf  5- try to implement caching if possible

Comment: Lovely.  What worked was altering the process managers as you specified (pm.max_children etc.)  I did not get around to #5.  ...If you'll write this up as an answer, I'll accept it.  I suggest putting in the correct spec for `fastcgi_pass` as well, as I had (obviously) messed that one up.  Tx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check following things,

1- `sudo service php5-fpm status`, try to start that if no running

2- while changing socket to tcp/ip remove unix, ie, in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file, in the php block change `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` to  `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` and in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` file change `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock` to `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`

3- try to increase the process managers for php, i.e., `pm.max_children=40`, `pm.start_servers = 10`, `pm.min_spare_servers = 5`, `pm.max_spare_servers = 10`

4- switch off keepalive connections from nginx.conf

5- try to implement [caching](http://www.techromance.com/2015/11/11/microcaching-in-nginx-web-server/) (is done for almost static content, so that all requests do not bother php) if possible.