# Connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: unix:, server

Tags: php, mysql, linux, wordpress, nginx

I have my Wordpress running on ec2 Amazon AMI. It was working fine with a good performance but last night I think Amazon internet service had a connectivity issue, and since I'm having difficulties to restore my website. When checking nginx error logs I see:

```
connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily  unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: unix:, server: _, request: "GETenter code here
```

I tried to restart mysql service and nginx but didn't work. Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Try deleting the file...first stop apache, then `rm /var/run/php-fpm.sock`, then start apache

Comment: thanks for comment. It's nginx not apache. I stopped it and deleted this file and started nginx again. Web site came back with an older version ( last 2 day posts lost) but in error log file same error persists, specially for the request of lost posts.   this page is automatically posting to facebook and when the users requests lost pages I see this error. When I try to connect to wp-admin I receive 502 Bad Gateway error

Comment: Can you post the full log line(the actual one ends with request: "GETenter code here)

Comment: 2016/09/26 13:15:33 [crit] 21581#0: *4011 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: unix:, server: _, request: "GET /amerika/abd-rusyayi-halepte-barbarlikla-sucladi HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "haber.land", referrer: "http://m.facebook.com/"

Comment: now the error message turned into this.

Comment: Stop nginx...now type `touch /var/run/php-fpm.sock`...then start nginx

Comment: If that doesn't works, then try changing in php-fpm pool configuration replace `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock` with `listen = 127.0.0.1:7777` and in `/etc/nginx/php_location` replace `fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock` with `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7777`
`

Comment: Getting the same issue for over a year now. I also get a `504 Gateway Timeout` error and have no choice but to restart nginx, this is becoming more and more frequent and I can't get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted the service

```
sudo systemctl restart php8.0-fpm.service
```

and bam! it worked.

Answer (score -1):

This is the best solution thread I've found for this problem so far:
 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/lemp-wordpress-php5-fpm-sock-failed

Answer (score -2):

1 - When you say it was working properly with good performance, and suddenly everything messed up, you might want to take back-up, and launch a fresh ec2 and start fresh again with same config.

2 - In case you might be assuming that you had good performance, and actually need optimization, you might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185268/502-bad-gateway/39218739#39218739) out.